# XSLT - If searched value exist more than once - Return only first

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I need (again) your expertise to solve my issue with XSLT.

I create a good working XSLT to transform/convert one (Payments) XML-Format to another. I´m using Excel as UI, Saxon9he with values from UI-Input in Excel and XSLT-Files to transform the files.

There are (two) four search criteria:

- (IBAN 1 & Amount 1)
- (IBAN 2 & Amount 2)

Everything is working fine, until the point if one of the searched values exists more than once in the input file.

Input-File: www.gudrich.com/xslt/input.xml

XSLT-File: http://www.gudrich.com/xslt/transform.xslt

To create this output file, the search parameter are:

- IBAN 1: DE02702203005005507393
- Amount 1: 19,00
- IBAN 2: DE13702203005003963537
- Amount 2: 804.07

Output-File: http://www.gudrich.com/xslt/output.xml

I only want that the first found result is transferred to the output file and the second must be ignored.

Actual it takes both found (IBAN) Transactions.

I also try the suggestion with Xpath and using [1]. 
But the result was that only the first element of the two search parameters will be considered.

Thank you & BR
Christian

Comment: Hi! It would help if you cut down the XSLT to the relevant and necessary elements, and provide a working example, e.g. with predefined values for variables like `$all_TxInf_Nodes`. Otherwise the problem remains obscure.

Comment: Yes, if you don't know the subject matter, debugging code that uses element names like `SCLSDD:BBkIDFBlkDirDeb` is an absolute nightmare. Give us a foo-bar simplified version please. And I'm not even sure I've understood exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are multiple items in your XML that match:

```
<xsl:if test="(number($betrag)=number($_find_amount2) and $iban=$_find_iban2)">
```

To constrain this to the first occurrence of `$iban=$_find_iban2` in the XML, you need something like:

```
<xsl:if test="(number($betrag)=number($_find_amount2) and $iban=$_find_iban2) and not(preceding::myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:DbtrAcct/myTxNS:Id/myTxNS:IBAN = $_find_iban2)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always select the first ocurrence using xslt and xpath, just add "[1]" at the end of your xpath expression.

You can take a look at this tutorial to understand better https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Here the problem is, that only the first searched value is in the output file. The second search value will be ignored :(

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to store in the variable "iban". A workaround to your code might be to define 2 variables `<xsl:variable name="iban" select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:DbtrAcct/myTxNS:Id/myTxNS:IBAN[1]"/>` and another variable `<xsl:variable name="iban2" select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:DbtrAcct/myTxNS:Id/myTxNS:IBAN[2]"/>` . You could only use this in case you are sure that the repeated will come at the end. If not I recommend you search how to delete/ignore duplicate elements in xslt.